# How do you change the size of the numbers on axes in Bokeh?

Tags: python, fonts, bokeh

For the plot in the image [colour magnitude diagram in Bokeh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvba0.png)
I am trying to get the numbers along the x and y axes to be larger. I have made the labels larger but I can't seem to find how to make the tick-mark numbers larger. I've tried `p1.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size` but that didn't work. Here's what I have so far. Thanks for any help!

```
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
p1 = figure(title = "Colour Magnitude diagram of M15 - 64s exposure using PIRATE",
      x_axis_label='Colour index (B-V)', 
      y_axis_label='Apparent V magnitude')
data_source = ColumnDataSource({'B_V':ClusterDataM15['B_V'],'V':ClusterDataM15['Vmag']})
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette='Magma256', low=max(ClusterDataM15['B_V']), high=min(ClusterDataM15['B_V']))
p1.scatter('B_V', 'V', source = data_source, color={'field': 'B_V', 'transform': color_mapper})
p1.y_range.flipped = True
p1.sizing_mode="stretch_both"
p1.add_tools(HoverTool())
p1.title.text_font_size = '20pt'
p1.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20pt"
p1.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20pt"
p1.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '20px'
p1.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '20px'
show(p1)
```

Comment: Hi Merle - I was able to change the x and y ticklabels (the numbers) using the `major_label_text_font_size`. Don't think there is a problem with your code

Comment: It's not changing the size of the numbers for my plot. The only things I was able to change were the title size and the label 'apparent v magnitude' etc.

Comment: Hi @Merle - think the issue is not with code, but with the environment. If you have another PC/server where you can run the code, try that. See if reinstalling the library helps. I tried this on python 3.8.8, bokeh 2.4.3 and Jupyter Notebook on Windows

Comment: Thanks @Redox, yes, the issue was the version.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code in a JupyterNotebook is working fine using the latest stable release bokeh 2.4.3.
The very basic example below

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(
    title = "Title",
    x_axis_label='X-Axis',
    y_axis_label='Y-Axis',
    width=300,
    height=300
)
p.line([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])
p.title.text_font_size = '20pt'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20pt"
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20pt"
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '20px'
p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '20px'
show(p)
```

will result in this plot:

[image: Basic line plot with changed text size]

Please check if you are running the lastes version. If not run `pip install bokeh -U`. If this does not help, please add some information about you computer and programming environment. If there is any error message or hint, please add this, too.

Comment: Thanks @mosc9575, that worked! It was the version.

Comment: If it works, would you please accept the answer as solution. Please press the check mark under the scoring arrows. This gives me and you some credit and other users see, that this is thread is solved.